# How to upgrade to python 3.5 from 2.7 in Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

How to upgrade from python 2.7 to 3.5 in Mac OSX? I downloaded python 3.5 .dmg file and installed it. what are the changes I should make for PYTHONPATH and PATH?

Is it possible to use both without any issues using virtualenv ?

Comment: I use both together on my laptop without issues.  I don't really modify my `PYTHONPATH` in my shell init scripts -- So I don't have issues with python2.7 module paths colliding with python3.5 paths due to using the wrong thing from `PYTHONPATH`... I also don't _rely_ on python3.5 -- Mostly it's for answering questions here :-).  I execute it via `python3` instead of `python`.  Anyway, I'm betting that _real_ wisdom here is that I'm playing with fire and should just bite the bullet and use `virtualenv` ;-)

Comment: #Animals/__init__.py 
from Mammals import Mammals
from Bird import Bird
#Animals/Mammals.py
class Mammals(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = ['Tiger']
    def print_members(self):
        for member in self.members :
            print('member :' + member)
#Animals/Bird.py 
class Bird(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.birds = ['sparrow']
    def print_members(self):
        for bird in self.birds:
            print('bird '+ bird)
#test.py
from Animals import Mammals,Bird
mam = Mammals()
bird = Bird()
mam.print_members()
bird.print_members()

Comment: I tend to invoke the version of Python I need whenever I create a new virtualenv with `mkvirtualenv`.  
e.g. `mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 nameofenv`

Comment: I did the same while creating a virtuanenv. But the problem was when I was importing a module from the other, it was not recognising from virtualenv. 
But it works fine when I am out of virtualenv and running it with python2.7

Comment: the one I posted above is the code. Due to space constraints, I cramped it.

Comment: You can use pyenv https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Answer (score 17):

There is no need to download .dmg file, just do it using "brew". You macbook is preinstalled with python2. To download python3, run this on terminal:

```
brew install python3
```

Comment: For anyone that happen to come upon this and needs version 3.5 since it's 3.6 now, use `brew switch python3 3.5.2_3`

Answer (score 3):

I you have python 2.x already installed then you can use `brew upgrade python` to upgrade to python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

had this issue as well. I navigated to the PATH location for both Python2.x and Python3.7. Updated with homebrew and hopefully the pip installer will work now.